# Fetching data with Supabase js and Next.js 13 returns an object (rather than array)

Tags: database, next.js, supabase, next.js13

I am trying to fetch data from a `Supabase` table called "profiles" with Next.js 13 and the app directory. I am trying to take advantage of the new `next.js` fetching methods, my code looks as follows:

```
export const revalidate = 0;

  export default async function getData() {
    const { data: profiles } = await supabase
      .from("profiles")
      .select("*")
      .eq("is_host", true);
    console.log(profiles);
    return { profiles };


 if (!profiles) {
   return <p>No hosts found</p>
 }
```

The problem is that this code seems to be wrapping the array returned from Supabase in an object.

The data returned looks like this:

```
{data: 
[
{
"id":"feef56d9-cb61-4c4d-88c6-8a8d7c9493d9",
"updated_at":null,
"username":"username",
"full_name":"Full Name",
"avatar_url":"URL",
"website":null,
"is_host":true,
"bio":null,
"languages":6
}
]
}
```

When I use `useState` and `useEffect` instead, the data is returned as expected, and I can map through it.

Does anybody have an idea why, and how I can prevent that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out, through a subsequent error, which I as able to solve thanks to the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75203676/typeerror-result-is-not-iterable-nextjs-13-data-fetching-with-getstaticpar) and the helpful hints I got from there.

`return { profiles };`

Returns the array inside an object.
By removing the {} I was able to fetch the array inside of it.