# "TypeError: result is not iterable" -> Nextjs 13 data fetching with getStaticParams

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase, supabase-database, next.js13

I am fetching data from a supabase database with the new fetching methods of Next js 13.
The fetching of my users to my listing page works well, and even when I click on their cards, the URL changes to the expected slug.

However, I seem to be unable to fetch the data unto the user's page, where it results in the following error:

```
TypeError: result is not iterable
```

My listings page looks like this:

```
export const revalidate = 60;

async function getData() {
  const {
    data
  } = await supabase.from("profiles").select().eq("is_host", true);
  return { data };
}

export default async function Hosts() {
  const data = await (getData());

  return ( 
<div > 
{data.data!.map((profile) => ( 
<div >
<Link href = {`/hosts/${profile.username}`}
          key = {profile.id} >
          </Link>
        ))
      } </div>
```

The profile page looks like this:

```
export const revalidate = 60;

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const { data: profiles } = await supabase.from("profiles").select("username");

const hostPath = profiles?.map((profile) => ({
  params: {host: profile.username},
}))
return {
  hostPath,
  fallback: false,
}
}

export default async function HostPage({ params: { username } }: {params: {username: string}}) {
  const {data: profile} = await supabase.from('profiles').select().match({username}).single()

return (
<div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(profile, null, 2)}</pre>
</div>
```

Both are serverside rendered.

Does anybody have any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: After removing the {} around the data in the return statement of the fetching method, everything works as expected (I was wrapping the array in an object, which can't be mapped).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is not iterable` is when you are trying to [iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) through a type that is not iterable.

here

```
const { data: profiles } =  await supabase.from("profiles").select("username");
```

`profiles` is not an array.

do you mean :

```
const hostPath = profiles?.data.map()
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I highly appreciate it. 
It seems as though the array coming from supabase through nextjs is being wrapped in an object. Do you have any idea what could be happening, and how to prevent it?
I will keep working on implementing your solution, though as of right now, this returns a lot of errors from Typescript. Thanks again.

Comment: `profiles?.data` should be an array I am not familiar with `supabase` but in your `listing` page you are mapping through `data.data!`

Comment: Yes, it's the only way I got it to work. I don't think supabase in itself has anything to do with it, when I fetch data with useEffect is actually works. I'm doing something wrong with the fetch code that wraps the data coming in into an object. Thank you for your effort

Comment: yes check your endpoint. you are welcome

Comment: Thank you for the input. Because of your statement about the endpoints I reviewed the code and after removing the {} around the data in the return statement of the fetching method, it now works like a charm. Thank you for taking the time.